# MySQL store procedure: How to declare a Cursor for a Select from a temporary table?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

In a MySQL Store Procedure, how can I declare a cursor for a Temporary Table which is created from a select statement.
Thanks,

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_foo`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_foo()
BEGIN   
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `TmpMyTable`;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `TmpMyTable` (
        `id`            INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `person_id`     INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `first_name`    VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
        `last_name`     VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
        INDEX `idx_first_name` (`person_id`),
        INDEX `idx_first_name` (`first_name`)
    ) ENGINE=MYISAM         
        SELECT 
            id AS `person_id`,
            first_name,
            last_name
        FROM person
    ;

    DECLARE _person_id INT(11); 
    DECLARE personCursor CURSOR 
    FOR 
        SELECT * FROM TmpMyTable;       

    OPEN personCursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH personCursor INTO _person_id;

        ...

    END LOOP;   
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why don't you just create your cursor using the select used in temp table creation? Creating temporary tables will generate lots of IO's. What is the added value of the temporary table in this case. It has only 3 fields, not likely to be updated. Please give more details about what is exactly required.

Comment: Thanks, Cedric for your input.

Comment: The problem is that I want to use the temp table multiple time and I don't want to execute the select multiple time!

Comment: I got it, just I used nested BEGIN..END blocks as stated in [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,40720,40872#msg-40872)

Answer (score 5):

In your example, make your cursor declaration before creating the temporary table. Seems illogical but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may create two separate procedures.
Like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `tmp_tbl`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE tmp_tbl()
BEGIN   
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `TmpMyTable`;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `TmpMyTable` (
        `id`            INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `person_id`     INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `first_name`    VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
        `last_name`     VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
        INDEX `idx_first_name` (`person_id`),
        INDEX `idx_first_name` (`first_name`)
    ) ENGINE=MYISAM         
        SELECT 
            id AS `person_id`,
            first_name,
            last_name
        FROM person
    ;   
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_foo`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_foo()
BEGIN   
    DECLARE _person_id INT(11); 
    DECLARE personCursor CURSOR 
    FOR 
        SELECT * FROM TmpMyTable;       

    OPEN personCursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH personCursor INTO _person_id;

        ...

    END LOOP;   
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And later you may call them sequentially.

```
call tmp_tbl();
call sp_foo();
```

Actually after you `BEGIN` the `PROCEDURE` you need to complete your declaration part.